# Is there a phenomenological real time, for Husserl?

Tags: time, death, phenomenology, realism

Is there a phenomenological real time, for Husserl? I've read some relevant sections, I think in the Crisis of the European Sciences, but could not determine an answer from them.

If it isn't, must we infer that time itself ends with death (meaning the termination of all experience)? I believe Husserl thought that impossible.

Comment: Husserl specifically refrains from passing judgment on "reality" of phenomenological experiences, it is controversial whether he was a realist or an anti-realist. But to him phenomenological is not the same as subjective, those experiences, including time, are constituted by the abstracted "transcendental ego", for which mere possibility of experience is enough, and that is not subject to death. Dispensing with such abstractions is one of Heidegger's points of departure from him.

Comment: yes i'm aware that the transcendental ego doesn't die. what's unclear is whether that's because there's a real time @Conifold

Comment: Then you can not infer that time ends with death regardless of whether it is "real" or not. In any case, questions about "reality" are bracketed in in phenomenology.

Comment: oh ok because it depends upon the transcendental ego alone @Conifold ?

Comment: he does in some places talk about a real or at least global (i forget) time. rather than ask the above question i should find those sections and type them out (edit it)

Comment: A good review is [Winkler, Husserl and Bergson on time and consciousness](https://www.academia.edu/604832/Husserl_and_bergson_on_time_and_consciousness). A recent critique of the notion of "reality" in transcendental idealism, concerning distant past in particular, is by Meillassoux, see [Ennis's essay](http://www.cosmosandhistory.org/index.php/journal/article/view/247/323).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92758/discussion-between-another-name-and-conifold).

Comment: i read the article (quickly) not clear whether, if "the transcendental subject is not merely ‘in time’, but experiences ‘time’ as temporality. Temporal experience is not a mere succession of points on the arrow of time, but the experiential feeling of having a past, living in the present, and looking to the future" then the transcendental ego does not depend upon time, one which is or isn't "real" for phenomenology. i.e. whether we can die phenomenologically? @Conifold

Comment: I admit I don't understand the questions you are asking, but some philosophers have written interesting pieces on nearby issues in Husserl exegesis:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227290095_Death_and_Time_in_Husserl's_C-Manuscripts

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-90-481-8766-9_4

Answer (score 1):

Husserlian concept of time and temporality is three-tiered:

1. Internal time consciousness
2. Subjective time
3. Worldly-objective time

And contrary to what you might think they arise from each other in 1 to 2 to 3 fashion, where the fundamental base for a worldly/global time and all time is the internal time the consciousness of the individual.

It is described here, for example, https://www.iep.utm.edu/phe-time/